# A software encrypted php file which cannot be decrypted forever

Tags: php, encryption

Actually i wanna run my php on my clients pc, so i should encrypt all my codes, can any method is there to encrypt which cannot be encrypted for sure? through any decryptors. please advice.

Comment: Your clients will always be able to read your code if you place it on their pc. Yes it's possible to encrypt your code, but they can always decrypt it.

Comment: One way to achieve what you want is using something like HipHop for PHP, which compiles your php code in native executable. Of course the code could be reverse engineered.

Comment: in general there is never a way to 100% protect your code if the client has to run it (even compiled code can be disassembled). And all encrypted stuff needs to be decrypted for execution especially in a scripting language like php. you can find obfuscators which will make it harder for your clients to understand the code, by removeing comments, renaming variable and function names to randomized stuff. but that will only slow them down if they really want to understand your code they will

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/753 Nope, it cannot be done.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski I don't think OP is asking about WB-Crypto, but rather obfuscation of program code. This one fits much better: [On the (Im)possibility of Obfuscating Programs](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PS/obf4.pdf) ([backup](http://eprint.iacr.org/2001/069))

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yay, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is literally impossible.

Think of it this way: **your client's computer needs to see the code**. And if your client's computer can see it, so can your client.

Of course you can slow your client down (as a trivial example, the sole act of coding slows non-programmers down in understanding the code), but a resourceful attacker can always break any encryption you create.
The reasoning behind this is simple: their computer does a predictable series of actions to execute the code (which obviously implies interpreting it), and you cannot prevent your client from doing that exact sequence as well, because doing so would prevent the code from being runnable at all.